# UIView Transition and DispatchQueue.main.async timing issue (in tableViewController)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, asynchronous

I am trying to create a table view that populates the initial view in illusion "realtime" where each cell flips over and then its value is displayed (as opposed to just showing up by default).  I have been tinkering with this for many hours now and cannot seem to figure out how to create a delay between when the flip occurs and when the label is shown.

I am using the isHidden value of the labels to determine when they are shown.  When the transition occurs after I am trying to change isHidden to true, but it seems that I am only able to have the value show up before the transition is done if I don't use a completion handler, or with the completion handler the animation does not show at all.  The section of my code is shown below:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testCell3", for: indexPath) as? FlipTableViewCell
        else{
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of AnimationTableViewCell.")
    }
    cell.flipLabel.text = String(array[indexPath.row])

    if(firstLoad){

        cell.isHidden = true
    }

    return cell
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


    firstLoad = false


    var delay:Double = 0

    for cell in self.tableView.visibleCells{



            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05*delay) {

                UIView.transition(with: cell.contentView, duration: 0.8, options: .transitionFlipFromTop, animations: nil, completion:{ doneWork in
                        if doneWork {

                            let cellTest = cell as? FlipTableViewCell
                            cellTest?.isHidden = false
                        }
                    })
            }

        delay = delay + 1

    }

}


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool){
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Here is the TableViewCell:

class FlipTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var flipLabel: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    flipLabel.isHidden = false
    flipLabel.alpha = 1
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

Comment: Please include your code inline, not as pictures.

Comment: Apologies, I have updated it